# Cron job sends every minute instead of specefic time

Tags: cron, cron-task

I have the following cron job:

```
* * 21 * * * wget -qO /dev/null http://myDomain/myController/myView
```

Which sends me a mail.

However as I can see from my now very full mail box I receive a mail every minute instead of every day at 21.00.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Apprently the type of linux machine im running needs to be `* */21 * * wget`

*Note the dash*

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a minute, so your cronjob will run every minute (*) at 21 hours, so 21:00 - 21:59.